# Paste text from clipboard without writing empty lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to paste info from the clipboard (usually some excel rows) to a .txt with python using the pyperclip library, but it writes all even lines as blank ones. I have been using this code:

```
s = pyperclip.paste() 
with open(filename ,"w") as g:
   g.write(s)
```

I tried to delete empty lines with

```
with open(filename,'r+') as g:
    for line in g:
        if not line.isspace():
            g.write(line)
```

but had no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out pyperclip is intended to be used solely with plain text.

Thankfully, Tkinter can also copy to and paste from clipboard. It works as supposed to with excel rows:

```
import tkinter as tk

filename = "file.txt"
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
clip_text = root.clipboard_get()

with open(filename ,"w") as g:
    g.write(clip_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If by a blank line you mean a line consisting only of spaces, you could try this:

```
def lineIsBlank(line):
    for char in line:
        if char != ' ':
             return False 
    return True 

for line in g:
    if !lineIsBlank(line):
        g.write(line)
```